Validator goes offline after setting wrong session keys
I am running solo chain with 4 validators.
What I did wrong: I rotated session keys of second validator and by mistake, I set those keys as a part of first validator>>Session Keys.
After that, when new era came in, block production went slow down and finalization was stopped.
After few eras, first validator was kicked out from active validators. Now I am not able to bring it back.
Can someone please help to fix this? How can I speed up block production and make block
finalization process start?

Just put the right session keys for the first validator and start the validator again from staking page in the explorer.
If the block production is still slow than you need to make grandpa_noteStalled transaction refer to below question for noteStalled.
Recovering from stalled finality (babe/grandpa)

I already tried. This is not working.

note_stalled didn't worked or validator didn't session keys
